# How to skip the code which produces error when dll is Missing in C#?

Tags: c#, dll, console

I have a Console Application in C# and a Class Library named `AppManager.cs`. The Method of this class is used in the `console Application` as given below.

```
         try
         {
            AppManager mgr = new AppManager(); //Want to skip this line when dll is missing.
            mgr.Method_Name(this, true);       //Want to skip this line when dll is missing.
         }
         catch (Exception)
         {
         }
```

When I have published the Code and extracted only exe then application fails to run [I know as the exe try to find that dll and method present in dll won't available].

**`Now my Question is That Is there any way to skip the code which will produce error when it will not find the reference of dll.`**

I also tried this but it didn't worked:

```
        String file = null;
        String filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        file = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "myLibrary.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
               .FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null)
        {
            AppManager mgr = new AppManager();
            mgr.Method_Name(this, true);
        }
```

Comment: Why do to you want to do this? How's your app run properly when dlls are missing? What problem you're trying to solve. Am pretty sure this is [XYProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Actually the dll override some default functionality which i don't want to perform when dll is missing.

Comment: Why would you allow dll to be missing? It is really unclear what is the underlying problem. Are you implementing a plugin?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Yes, it is something like plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you do that, it won't give the desired output too. Why don't you integrate the dll with your exe? You can do it by using this [tool](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Can you not simply check if the dll exists or not?

```
string filePath = @"SOME_PATH";
var exists = File.Exists(filePath);
if(exists)
{
    AppManager mgr = new AppManager();
    mgr.Method_Name(this, true);   
}
```

Comment: What about GAC? Version?, StrongName? assembly private path? etc